# Export php file output to PDF file (Hebrew output)

Tags: php, pdf

Im tried to export the output of my php file.
For example, I have this php file:

```
<?php
echo "שלום!";
?>
```

I tried the tcpdf class, in the expamples folder there is a file that crate pdf with html code, the example 61 or 6 [here.](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php)

The problem is when I try to take the html output by file_get_content and the content is in Hebrew the content of the pdf is "???????" or somthing like this.

Any idea how I can export my hebrew output to pdf?

I also tried fpdf and others libraries and I didn't succeed.

Help please.

Thanks

Comment: is your hebrew font in the tcpdf fonts directory? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034219/tcpdf-font-doesnt-display-special-characters

Comment: I tried what he suggest..not working..still "?????" instead hebrew.

Comment: same problem was solved when I used 'freesans' - font that supports Hebrew characters

Answer (score 1):

```
font-family: firefly, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;
```

Use this `font-family` attribute on your hebrew letter contain element.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor - use snappy to create PDF from HTML, unlike dompdf it supports **all** languages, directions etc.

(The package itself is just a wrapper, it uses an external library - wkhtmltopd to create the pdf).

It will render pretty much anything in any language, Hebrew included -
https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy